# Set specific colour map to Bar-chart with callback - dash Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I've got an interactive bar chart that displays counts from days of the week. I'm trying to set the color map so each day of the week maintains the same color. At the moment, if I remove any days, the color changes.

Separately, is it possible to keep the same dropdown values for days of the week and map the same color sequence but plot `DATES` instead of days of the week?

```
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
       'Type': ['A','B','B','B','C','C','D','E','E','E','E','F','F','F'],
       })

N = 30
df = pd.concat([df] * N, ignore_index=True)

df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.date_range(start='2022/01/01 07:30', end='2022/01/30 08:30', periods=len(df))
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], dayfirst = True).sort_values()
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.floor('1min')
df['DATE'], df['TIME'] = zip(*[(d.date(), d.time()) for d in df['TIMESTAMP']])
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['YEAR'] = df['DATE'].dt.year

df = df.sort_values(by = 'DATE')

df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.weekday
df = df.sort_values('DOW').reset_index(drop=True)
df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.day_name()


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

filter_box = html.Div(children=[
    ################### Filter box ###################### 
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label('Day of the week:', style={'paddingTop': '2rem'}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='DOW',
            options=[
                {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df['DOW'].unique()
            ],
            value=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday'],
            multi=True
        ),

    ], className="four columns",
    style={'padding':'2rem', 'margin':'1rem'} )

])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(filter_box, className="bg-secondary h-100"), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'date-bar-chart'), style={
                        "padding-bottom": "10px",
                    },),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
            ]),
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(),
            ]),
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)


@app.callback(
    Output('date-bar-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("DOW", "value"),
    ])     

def date_chart(dow):

    dff = df[df['DOW'].isin(dow)]
    count = dff['DOW'].value_counts()

    dff['Color'] = dff['DOW'].map(dict(zip(dff['DOW'].unique(),
                    px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[:len(dff['DOW'].unique())])))

    Color = dff['Color'].unique()
    Category = dff['DOW'].unique()

    cats = dict(zip(Color, Category)) 

    data = px.bar(x = count.index, 
                  y = count.values,
                  color = count.index,
                  color_discrete_map = cats,
                 )
              
    layout = go.Layout(title = 'Date')
    fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout) 

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8051)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting `cats` in your callback so each time your dff change based on filter, your dict will be changed. So that I think you should define your `color_discrete_map` with df, not dff. And I think you should change your cats to `cats = dict(zip(Category,Color))`

```
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
       'Type': ['A','B','B','B','C','C','D','E','E','E','E','F','F','F'],
       })

N = 30
df = pd.concat([df] * N, ignore_index=True)

df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.date_range(start='2022/01/01 07:30', end='2022/01/30 08:30', periods=len(df))
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], dayfirst = True).sort_values()
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.floor('1min')
df['DATE'], df['TIME'] = zip(*[(d.date(), d.time()) for d in df['TIMESTAMP']])
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['YEAR'] = df['DATE'].dt.year

df = df.sort_values(by = 'DATE')

df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.weekday
df = df.sort_values('DOW').reset_index(drop=True)
df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.day_name()
df['Color'] = df['DOW'].map(dict(zip(df['DOW'].unique(),
                    px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[:len(df['DOW'].unique())])))

Color = df['Color'].unique()
Category = df['DOW'].unique()

cats = dict(zip(Category,Color)) 

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

filter_box = html.Div(children=[
    ################### Filter box ###################### 
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label('Day of the week:', style={'paddingTop': '2rem'}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='DOW',
            options=[
                {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df['DOW'].unique()
            ],
            value=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday'],
            multi=True
        ),

    ], className="four columns",
    style={'padding':'2rem', 'margin':'1rem'} )

])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(filter_box, className="bg-secondary h-100"), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'date-bar-chart'), style={
                        "padding-bottom": "10px",
                    },),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
            ]),
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(),
            ]),
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)


@app.callback(
    Output('date-bar-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("DOW", "value"),
    ])     

def date_chart(dow):

    dff = df[df['DOW'].isin(dow)]
    count = dff['DOW'].value_counts()
    data = px.bar(x = count.index, 
                  y = count.values,
                  color = count.index,
                  color_discrete_map = cats,
                 )
              

    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port = 8051)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've assigned a dict to `color_discrete_map` with `cats` though right and it doesnt work? Is there a way I can use a function that takes n number of inputs. Rather than hard-coding colors for each input?

Comment: @Chopin: Because you are setting it in callback with dff so each time dff change based on filter, your dict will change. So I think you should define cats with df, not dff in callback. I will update my answer.

Comment: FYI, see my answer for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is too complicated and doesn't answer the second question.

For the first question on the `color_discrete_map` parameter, you should define a proper dictionary with keys as week day names and values as colors like this. You don't need `df['Color']`, `Color`, `Category`, etc.

```
import pandas as pd
...
color_map = {
    pd.Timestamp(2023, 2, 13+i).day_name(): # 2-13 was monday.
        px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[i]
            for i in range(7)
}
...
def date_chart(dow):
    dff = df[df['DOW'].isin(dow)]
    count = dff['DOW'].value_counts()
    data = px.bar(x = count.index,
                  y = count.values,
                  color = count.index,
                  color_discrete_map = color_map,
    )
    ...
```

For the second question, you need a logic to choose one of the rows matching a given week day. The following is one example which chooses the first one.(This uses the `group_by()`, so the `value_counts()` is not necessary.)

```
def date_chart(dow):
    dff = df[df['DOW'].isin(dow)]
    g = dff.groupby('DOW', as_index=False)
    g_df = g.head(1).merge(g.size())
    data = px.bar(x = g_df['DATE'],
                  y = g_df['size'],
                  color = g_df['DOW'],
                  color_discrete_map = color_map,
    )
    ...
```

Comment: thanks but if I groupby `DOW`, I'll only ever plot 7 values. This only works if I have < 1 weeks worth of data.

Comment: You are already plotting 7 values at max by using ```value_counts```. What do you want exactly?

Comment: I groupbed by`DAY` and `DOW`. All good. Thanks for this.